PostgreSQL COPY command is much slower locally compared to remote server with identical specs
I'm encountering a performance issue with the PostgreSQL COPY command when running it locally. Specifically, my .csv files are on my local machine, and I am pushing them into a remote PostgreSQL server using COPY. Both my remote backend app server and my local PC have identical specs (both with SSDs, similar RAM, and CPU cores). The PostgreSQL database itself is hosted on a different remote server and can only be accessed through a specific whitelisted internet connection.
Configuration

Cores: 8
RAM: 16 GB
Disk Space: 100 GB (50% free)
OS: Linux Ubuntu
Django: 5.1
Python: 3.11

The issue is that the COPY command runs significantly slower on my local machine compared to the remote server, even though both environments are very similar. My local PC is connected to the internet through VPN, which is also fast. When I run the code below locally, it is much slower compared to when I run it on the server. I also noticed another problem: establishing a connection via PSQL, pgAdmin, DBeaver, etc., becomes extremely slow when I am running the process locally. Many times, it doesn't connect to the remote database. I am not sure if this problem is caused by multiprocessing or a different broadband connection.
Here's a snippet of my code:
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import psycopg2


def get_connection(env):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(f"""postgresql://{env["USER"]}:{env["PASSWORD"]}@{env["HOST"]}:{env["PORT"]}/{env["NAME"]}""")
    try:
        yield conn
    finally:
        conn.close()

def copy_from(file_path: str, table_name: str, env, column_string: str):
    with get_connection(env) as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            with open(file_path, "r") as f:
                query = f"COPY {table_name} ({column_string}) FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER FALSE, DELIMITER ',', NULL '')"
                cursor.copy_expert(query, f)
        connection.commit()


with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
    p.map(partial(copy_from, table_name=table_name, env=env, column_string=column_string), file_path_list)

Local Machine
OS: Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Seqrite EndPoint Security
Traceroute Result:

Gateway: ~3.5 ms
Intermediate Hops: 6.5 ms to 40.7 ms
Final Hops: 7.7 ms to 12.7 ms

Remote Server
OS: Linux Ubuntu
Traceroute Result:

Gateway: ~0.2 ms to 0.7 ms
Intermediate Hops: All responses are either not available or < 1 ms

Questions:

Why might the COPY command be slower locally despite similar specs and a fast internet connection?
Are there any specific optimizations or configurations I should check on my local machine to improve performance?
Could network latency or other factors be impacting the local performance, and if so, how can I address this?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Your can run traceroute targeted at the db, from your local PC and the remote server to see the difference between paths from either up to the db. Jumping through a VPN could be a bottleneck, among other things. Could be high bandwidth, low throughput. It would be great if you could also say something more about the size of the file, how you measure this relative performance and what results you get exactly: SSDs aren't all the same and it could even be SATA vs NVME that accounts for it.

What is the actual latency and bandwidth between server and client?

Is your local PC running Windows with an anti-virus that intercepts disk writes?

I've added latency results. I use Linux Ubuntu and Seqrite antivirus.

Can you reproduce this with a simpler test case without the partial and multiprocessing and glob and os modules?  Better yet, can you reproduce this just with using \copy from psql?  Also, what is a "HIT"?

I've removed the os module, 'HIT', and multiprocessing. By 'HIT', I meant I ran traceroute  twice within 10 minutes to get an average network latency.

Are you saying copying a local file to a remote server is slower than copying a local file to a local server? That is, are you copying to the same server each time, only the client has moved?

Maybe I am not understanding correctly, but isn't "remote" version copying locally (same remote machine)? And your "local" version is copying from other machine? Those timings (<1ms vs 40ms) kind of suggest that

How large is this CSV file?


The PostgreSQL database itself is hosted on a different remote server and can only be accessed through a specific whitelisted internet connection.
...
My local PC is connected to the internet through VPN, which is also fast.

I can't say without more information, but the difference in performance can simply be attributed to having to send large amounts of data over the internet through a VPN.
You provided latency numbers, but that's not relevant for a sustained transfer of large amounts of data; I presume the CSV is large because you wouldn't be noticing a problem with a small CSV. What is relevant for COPY is sustained transfer rates. That's what you should be testing.
Latency is how long it takes to get a response. Transfer rates are how fast data can be pushed through. To use a plumbing analogy, latency is how long it takes after turning on the tap to get water, transfer rates are how much water can come through the pipes. Your transfer rates are only as fast as the slowest pipe, and that's probably the VPN.
Managed networks can have two data transfer rates: a fast rate for the initial data, and then a slower rate for more data. Small files transfer fast, large files start fast then get slower. Since most operations transfer a lot of small files (consider a web page with small images and text files) this makes the connection feel fast for most things. But transfer a large file, like a large CSV, and things slow down. This is to conserve bandwidth while keeping the connection feeling snappy.
What you should be looking into is the sustained transfer rates to the server. Try using scp to transfer the CSV file to the server and see how long that takes.
